# System.AccessViolationException was unhandled c# Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I started to port my Windows Phone 7 application to Windows Phone 8 and realized that I was not getting results in my ListBox.  When run normally, my code only throws an exception when I step into the "new ActiveItem" part of the code.  I verified that the XML is getting returned and the elements are accurate, but I have never seen this before.  Any suggestions?

```
EventsListBox.ItemsSource = from activeweb in xmlItems.Descendants("meta")

select new ActiveItem
{
ActEvent = activeweb.Element("assetName").Value.Trim(),
Date = activeweb.Element("city").Value + ", " + activeweb.Element("Eventstate").Value +
Environment.NewLine +
Convert.ToDateTime(activeweb.Element("startDate").Value).ToLongDateString(),
City = activeweb.Element("city").Value,
StartTime = activeweb.Element("startTime").Value,
AssetId = activeweb.Element("assetId").Value.Trim()
};
```

Here is the constructor for ActiveItem

```
public class ActiveItem

{

public string ActEvent { get; set; }

public string Date { get; set; }

public string State { get; set; }

public string City { get; set; }

public string StartTime { get; set; }

public string AssetId { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the CallStack of the exception:

> BeActive.DLL!BeActive.MainPage.activeweb_DownloadStringCompleted.AnonymousMethod__1(System.Xml.Linq.XElement activeweb) Line 97 C#

Comment: Does your ActiveItem class have a default constructor?

Comment: Could you add the full callstack of your exception?

Comment: Here is how I am constructing ActiveItem

`

public class ActiveItem

{

public string ActEvent { get; set; }

public string Date { get; set; }

public string State { get; set; }

public string City { get; set; }

public string StartTime { get; set; }

public string AssetId { get; set; }

}
`

Comment: @KooKiz -  Here is the callstack.  I added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many attempts/rebuilds, I think I found the issue.  I deleted the listbox from my XAML and added the "LongListSelector" (since this is the replacement for ListBox).  From there, I changed the XAML code to represent ListBox and it all worked.  Something must have gone wrong during the upgrade to the Windows Phone 8 compilation.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the ItemsSource on the background thread instead of the UI thread?

I'd suggest wrapping your code in this:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
        EventsListBox.ItemsSource = from activeweb ...
    });
```

Comment: I just tried wrapping the code in that and received the same error.